# how to store result of multiple select sql query in a python object.Be it list,tuple or dataframe. Cursor.Fetchall() holds only last execution result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sqlite

```
query = pd.read_csv('input_query.csv')
query_list = query['DB_QUERY'].tolist()
length = len(query_list)
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(length):
    sql1 = query_list(i)
    cusror1 = conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute(sql1)
    result = cursor.fetchall() 
    if result_df.empty():
       result_df = result
    else:
       result_df = result.append(cursor1.fetchall(),ignore_index = True)
    result_df.to_csv('query_result.csv')
```

I have tried using a nested for loop for writing result to a dataframe as well but it writes only last execution.
My input CSV has list of select statements that needs to be executed.

Comment: Why are you appending `cursor1.fetchall()` to `result` (which already holds the contents of that cursor), when you want instead to append `result` to the `result_df`? You understand? `result` and `cursor.fetchall()` are one in the same. You want to append either of those to dataframe. You don't want to append them to themselves.

Comment: Thanks Alot!! This Worked. Now I am getting my result in a dataframe. But the return type of fetchall is list of tuples and in the CSV the result is in single column separated by comma. How I can convert it to multiple columns.

Comment: I think that's worth opening a new question for :)